# Complexity of algorithms in Big O notation

Tags: data-structures, complexity-theory, big-o

What is Big O notation and why do we measure complexity of any algorithm in Big O notation?
An example will do the good.

Answer (score 1):

You must check **[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)**

> In mathematics, big O notation describes the limiting behavior of a
>   function when the argument tends towards a particular value or
>   infinity, usually in terms of simpler functions. It is a member of a
>   larger family of notations that is called Landau notation,
>   Bachmann–Landau notation (after Edmund Landau and Paul Bachmann), or
>   asymptotic notation. In computer science, big O notation is used to
>   classify algorithms by how they respond (e.g., in their processing
>   time or working space requirements) to changes in input size. In
>   analytic number theory, it is used to estimate the "error committed"
>   while replacing the asymptotic size, or asymptotic mean size, of an
>   arithmetical function, by the value, or mean value, it takes at a
>   large finite argument. A famous example is the problem of estimating
>   the remainder term in the prime number theorem.